# Аутентификация с помощью одноклассников

Tags: веб-программирование, api, авторизация, odnoklassniki-api

Как описано [тут](https://apiok.ru/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42476652) сделал первые 3 шага, а после этого не знаю что делать.
В 4->б написано:

> После получения ключа доступа access_token ваше приложение получит возможность совершать запросы к API от имени авторизованного пользователя.

Но я ни какой **access_token** не получил.

Answer (score 1):

Ваше приложение получит `access_token` как результат выполнения 4-го шага - когда конечный пользователь согласится дать приложению требуемые права.

До завершения выполнения этого шага, `access_token` нигде не используется. Вы сейчас просто забежали вперед.